# How to use `moment` to convert timestamp to week of the year

Tags: creation-timestamp

I need to convert the timestamp to the week of the year, and use it with the time selector of antd. I only found the following method, which is the method to get the week of the month. Does anyone know how to get the week of the year?

```js
function weekOfMonth (m: any) {
    return Math.ceil(m.date() / 7);
}

function getYearWeek (weekData: any) {
    const startDate = moment(weekData).startOf('week');
    let weekMonth = weekOfMonth(startDate);
    let date = startDate.format('YYYY年MM月');
    return `${date}第${weekMonth}周`;
}
```

Comment: Please notice, that `momentjs` is deprecated and its authors generally advise *against* using it for new projects https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 0):

1. week of the year

`w` 1 2 ... 52 53

`wo` 1st 2nd ... 52nd 53rd

`ww` 01 02 ... 52 53

2. week of the year (ISO)

`W` 1 2 ... 52 53

`Wo` 1st 2nd ... 52nd 53rd

`WW` 01 02 ... 52 53

Just `moment().format('W')` will do